# Where does yarn keep global packages?

Tags: yarnpkg

How do I find the directory where `yarn` keeps global packages?

What are the defaults, and how do I find the value based on current configuration?

Answer (score 9):

[The default global directories are](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2049#issuecomment-263183768):

- `$Env:LOCALAPPDATA/yarn/config/global/node_modules` on Windows
- `~/.config/yarn/global` on OSX and non-root Linux
- `/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global` on Linux if logged in as root

*This directory can be overridden* by either `npm` or `yarn`'s `prefix`, so to get the current value, use:

```
yarn global dir
```

Comment: If you're looking for `link`ed packages, check `.config/yarn/link`.

Comment: does this still apply to latest version of yarn?